# java.lang.VerifyError: JVMVRFY027 receiver is incompatible with declaring class; class=org/primefaces/component/gmap/GMap, method=queueEvent

Tags: jsf, primefaces, websphere, jsf-2.2, websphere-8

I'm facing a problem, when I try to run my application on WebSphere 8.5.

```
FFDC Exception:com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.exception.WebAppNotLoadedException SourceId:com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer ProbeId:736 Reporter:com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer@e152ede7
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.exception.WebAppNotLoadedException: Failed to load webapp: JVMVRFY027 receiver is incompatible with declaring class&#59; class=org/primefaces/component/gmap/GMap, method=queueEvent&#40;Ljavax/faces/event/FacesEvent
&#59;&#41;V, pc=676
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.VirtualHostImpl.addWebApplication(VirtualHostImpl.java:176)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApp(WSWebContainer.java:749)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApplication(WSWebContainer.java:634)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.install(WebContainerImpl.java:426)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.start(WebContainerImpl.java:718)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1177)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectStart(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1370)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:639)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:968)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:776)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplicationDynamically(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1379)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2189)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:389)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitImpl.start(CompositionUnitImpl.java:123)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:332)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.access$500(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:119)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl$1.run(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:607)
        at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAs(ContextManagerImpl.java:5474)
        at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAsSystem(ContextManagerImpl.java:5600)
        at com.ibm.ws.security.core.SecurityContext.runAsSystem(SecurityContext.java:255)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCompositionUnit(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:621)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCompositionUnit(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:565)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1269)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
        at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:69)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor61.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
        at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:272)
        at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean$4.run(RequiredModelMBean.java:1152)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:298)
        at com.ibm.oti.security.CheckedAccessControlContext.securityCheck(CheckedAccessControlContext.java:30)
        at sun.misc.JavaSecurityAccessWrapper.doIntersectionPrivilege(JavaSecurityAccessWrapper.java:41)
        at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invokeMethod(RequiredModelMBean.java:1146)
        at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invoke(RequiredModelMBean.java:999)
        at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:847)
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:783)
        at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl$1.run(AdminServiceImpl.java:1335)
        at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:118)
        at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl.invoke(AdminServiceImpl.java:1228)
        at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.AdminServiceDelegator.invoke(AdminServiceDelegator.java:181)
        at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.ipc.CallRouter.route(CallRouter.java:247)
        at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.ipc.IPCConnectorInboundLink.doWork(IPCConnectorInboundLink.java:360)
        at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.ipc.IPCConnectorInboundLink$IPCConnectorReadCallback.complete(IPCConnectorInboundLink.java:602)
        at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLReadServiceContext$SSLReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLReadServiceContext.java:1818)
        at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
        at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
        at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
        at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
        at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
        at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
        at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
        at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1864)
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: JVMVRFY027 receiver is incompatible with declaring class; class=org/primefaces/component/gmap/GMap, method=queueEvent(Ljavax/faces/event/FacesEvent;)V, pc=676
        at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verifyImpl(Native Method)
        at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verify(J9VMInternals.java:94)
        at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:171)
```

The problem seems to be the version of PrimeFaces or javax faces but I do not even use GMAP object in my project.

On tomcat 7, everything is right and works fine but when I try to load my app in WebSphere this blows up.

I am using PrimeFaces 5 and javax.faces.2.2.0

**UPDATE**

before Gas answer, i changed with eclipse the project facet. i changed the web-module (3.0),jst.jsf(2.2) and java version (1.6).

it all works fine, as ever, on tomcat but in WS it does show me the same error.

this is so frustrating.

**UPDATE**

after 7 days i just cannot figure it out. it seems that WAS 8.5.5 won't work.
now it gives continously:

```
Failed to load webapp: javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer: Provider       com.sun.faces.config.FacesInitializer not a subtype
```

I followed this links to try to solve the problem:

[IBM using jsf 2.0](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014532308) (I'm using shared library- parent last already and i changed "jsp and JSF options" in every way it is possible)

I had also search for all the libs and dependencies on maven rep.

i am using:

javax.el-api-2.2.1.jar

javax.faces-2.2.0.jar

javax.servlet.jsp-api-2.2.1.jar

javax.servlet-api-3.0.1.jar

what am I doing wrong?

I have to say that all this works on IBM Liberty 8.5 and Apache tomcat 7

**UPDATE**
yes, according to this link: [Ibm websphere problem](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014727994)

I tried to do as listed:Under WAS:

```
1) Under RAD produce a Ear File
2) Start the admin console
3) Panel: Environment (at right)
4) Sub-menu: Shared libraries
5) Button New and select the required fields. Read with attention the                             tooltip on each field
 6) Check the box Class Loading - Use an isolated class loader for this shared library 
 7) Panel: Applications > Application Types > WebSphere enterprise applications
 8) Button: Install, select your ear and Next
 9) Select the radio button: Detailed - Show all installation options and parameters.
 10) Follow the steps - moslty default value are ok
 10.1) Step 4 Map shared libraries
 10.2) Select your ear
 10.3) Button: References Shared Libraries
 10.4) Select your library previously created and OK button
 10.5) Follow the next steps and start your ear file

 10.a) If it does not work, then try to create a class loader Panel: Servers > Server Types > WebSphere application servers > Your server (server1)
 10.b) Panel: Server Infrastructure > Java and Process Management > Class loader
 10.c) Button New: > Class loader order > Classes loaded with local class loader first (Parent Last)
 10.d) Apply Button
 10.e) Then at the same panel: Shared library references link
 10.f) Button Add and select your shared library, OK and Save
 10.g) Restart your server and your application
```

Comment: Are you including any of these javax.servlet-api-3.0.1.jar, javax.el-api-2.2.1.jar, javax.servlet.jsp-api-2.2.1.jar in the WEB-INF/lib or shared library? Then remove them. Please provide which jars you have in WEB-INF/lib and which you defined in the shared library.

Comment: Hi gas, thank you for your reply. All my jars are defined in my shared library (even hibernate, poi, etc)and they are not in WEB-INF/lib folder. javax.servlet-api-3.0.1.jar, javax.el-api-2.2.1.jar, javax.servlet.jsp-api-2.2.1.jar are in my shared folder. Do i have to delete them from shared library and put them in the WEB-INF/LIB? Or viceversa? Thank you again

Comment: I just removed those libraries from share folder (javax.servlet-api-3.0.1.jar, javax.el-api-2.2.1.jar, javax.servlet.jsp-api-2.2.1.jar) but  nothing happened. just the same error again :'(

Comment: Did you created **isolated** shared library? Also list in the question all the jars you have in shared lib and all you have in web-inf/lib.

Comment: @Gas I update the question because it is to long to write here

Comment: @Gas i will post the list later, i cannot post the image of them due to a reputation problem

Comment: hello @Gas thanks again. i just solved it. ihad to create an ear project with eclipse and i had to set in project facet "websphere application Co existence" (i had to download a plugin). in my shared library now i put theese files: el-impl-2.2.jar,javax.faces-2.2.0,primefaces-5.0. i will post all the steps that i made as soon as possible. Thanks a lot again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've succeeded to fix this issue by cleaning manually websphere caches and installations and rebuilding from the start. Used `/bin/clearClassCache` script and deleted files manually from `c:\users\User\AppData\Local\javasharedresources\`.
Rebuilt and redeployed the application - and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

WebSphere comes with JSF 2.0 (MyFaces). To use your own implementation you need to change the JSF configuration. Check this page [Configuring JavaServer Faces implementation](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/api/content/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/tweb_jsf.html?locale=en). It explains in details what you have to do (basically - create isolated shared library and configure JSF settings)